# Updating Form in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have one modal popup in which I have added a name and description and after creating it will display value in the same popup. Similarly I have added edit functionality after clicking on edit, edit form will be open and after editing it should update. But what's my problem is that at the time of editing form the value is coming on typing the value is also displaying in display section.
This is my modal popup edit form

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="edit(projectValue.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" #name="ngModel">   
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="submit" [disabled]="name.errors">Update project</button>
   </form>
   <div *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <b>{{project.name}}</b>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right" (click) = "openEditForm(project)">    </i>
```

This is my project.component.ts

```
   project = new Project();
   projectValue = new Project();
   fetchprojects(){
     this.authService.getProjects().subscribe(
     projectsData => {
     this.projects.push(this.projects);
     this.projects = projectsData;  
     },
    err => {
      console.log('err:', err);
     }
    );
   };
   openEditForm(projectVlaue){
     this.editForm = true;
     this.projectValue = projectValue;
    };

   edit(projecValue) {
     this.projectValue = projectValue;
     this.authService.updateProject(this.projectValue).subscribe(
     project=> {
      this.updatedStatus = true;
     }
    }
  );
};
```

Can any one please help me in this?

Comment: You are trying to say that While you are under edit form, whatever changes you are making is directly visible in your display section without clicking on Update button?

Comment: Can you show your code for modal pop up?

Comment: Yes @TheDictator, Could you please provide me solution regarding this.

Comment: Because you are using ngModel

Comment: Then how we will update the attribute without ngModel? Could you explain me with some example.

Comment: Include modal code in question.

Comment: I have already added modal popup code in question @developer038.